# Android Custom Facebook Log In Button

Tags: android, facebook

I created custom button which works fine in my emulator. However, on the device it does not work: for the first time it logs in but at the second try it does perform any action.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton btn = new LoginButton(MainActivity.this);
            btn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                    "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));

            if (Profile.getCurrentProfile().getCurrentProfile() != null) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
                currentButton.setText("LOG IN");
            } else {
                btn.performClick();
                Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
                currentButton.setText("LOG OUT");
            }
        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


                    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                                        // handle error
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {

                                        try {

                                            user_name = json.getString("name");
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            System.out.println(user_name);
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, user_name);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }

                            }).executeAsync();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                }
            });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

The application made public in facebook configuration page. Standard LoginButton works fine, however, I need to make it custom, or at least, to change button shape and color. Any ideas how to do that? Thank you in advance.

Facebook SDK version: 4.5 
Emulator/device API versions: 23/21 (respectively)

Comment: Do any of the facebook callback methods get called the second time?

Comment: @NoobDogg Yes, onError method was called

Comment: What was the exception ?

Comment: @NoobDogg no exception was called, I just checked it using logcat

Comment: @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                }  what was the FacebookException ?

Comment: @NoobDogg I just resolved the problem, it was about key hashes which was generated with a new app. I just added one in facebook app settings. Thank you very much, the cause of the problem was not obvious for me until I checked explicitly exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by newly generated key hash. Resolved the problem by adding new one (from stack trace) to the facebook application setttings.